# Http Monitor in C#

Tags: c#, http, sockets, proxy

this is my code for Monitoring Http:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     try
     {
          byte[] input = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
          Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
          s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80));
          s.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, input, null);
          s.BeginReceive(arrResponseBytes, 0, arrResponseBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnClientReceive), s);
          System.Threading.ManualResetEvent reset = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
          reset.WaitOne();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
}

static byte[] arrResponseBytes = new byte[1024 * 5];
protected static void OnClientReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
     Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
     int count = socket.EndReceive(ar);
     if (count > 0)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(arrResponseBytes, 0, count));
          socket.BeginReceive(arrResponseBytes, 0, arrResponseBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnClientReceive), socket);
     }
}
```

but i cannot get http hosts.
I do not know what data.
i want to get http host for example:
http://google.com
how can i monitor system http?
thanks.

Comment: this is my data:http://hamishebaharp30world.persiangig.com/Pics/Use/http%20monitoring.jpg

Comment: Did you try to decompress it? It is possible to compress on the server side (which is told by a header), then you'll just see garbage. Anyhow, I'm not sure whether you can distinguish between different requests, but as I said, I'm not sure if this may become a problem.

Comment: How do you fiddler software?i want to get browsers resuests.

Comment: I'm using http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ - I tend not to reinvent the wheel as long as others probably know more about it or I absolutely miss a feature. BTW: Fiddler works as a proxy

Comment: Regarding: https is a somewhat harder thing: you need to fake a certificate (kind of man in the middle) which will light up the typical warning on the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in your link is the [IP + TCP headers](http://nmap.org/book/tcpip-ref.html). You should parse the IP&TCP headers to extract the content. TCP content starts *approximately* at offset 40. So you can try your program's modified version as below to see the content of each **HTTP** request. (Working but not complete program just to give you an idea)

PS: See the `s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 80));`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] input = new byte[]{1};
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 80));
        s.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll , input, null);
        s.BeginReceive(arrResponseBytes, 0, arrResponseBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnClientReceive), s);
        System.Threading.ManualResetEvent reset = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
        reset.WaitOne();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static byte[] arrResponseBytes = new byte[1024 * 64];
static void OnClientReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    int count = socket.EndReceive(ar);
    if (count >= 40)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arrResponseBytes, 40, count - 40);
            string bin = BitConverter.ToString(arrResponseBytes, 40, count - 40).Replace("-", " ");
            if(s.StartsWith("GET"))
                Console.WriteLine(s + " - " + bin);
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch { }
    }
    socket.BeginReceive(arrResponseBytes, 0, arrResponseBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnClientReceive), socket);
}
```

Comment: I attempted to create a new console application using this code and nothing seems to be happening.