# Https monitor in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, https

I've made a small application for monitoring http traffic by following this post:

[Monitor http port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392250/http-monitor-in-c-sharp#)

How can I monitor https (Port 443) traffic? When I set the port to 443, I can't receive anything.

Thanks

Comment: As Sascha commented in the referenced post, why don't you use Fiddler? Fiddler can even do HTTPS. Also, keep in mind that with HTTPS a client will first establish a secure channel with the server endpoint and only after that send HTTP data in encrypted fashion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But for a project I need to implement it by myself in C#. So I need to find a way to monitor port 443.